# How to rotate image by 360 degree with different images, on touch event?

Tags: android, android-layout

I had go through lot of links but still I am confuse how to do it.

I have total 60 images of one object with different angle.When user swipe image right  or left  then I should be show the particular angle image like image is rotating automatically.

Please suggest me the right way to do so.

Comment: Could you please explain how to achieved it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Matrix rotation.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(orientation);
Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: Will you explain in more detail please..?

Comment: src is the source Bitmap. orientation is the rotation angle. So matrix.postRotate(90) will rotate your original bitmap by 90 degrees.